# Erro no fechamento da tag php

Tags: php

Meu codigo esta dando o erro

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdo...

Quando vejo onde é o erro, é no fechamento da tag `<?php`.

O que poderia estar acontecendo?

```
<?php 
    require_once('db.class.php'); 
    $usuarios = $_POST['usuario']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $senha = md5($_POST['senha']); 
    $objDB= new db(); 
    $link= $objDB->conecta_mysql(); 
    $usuario_exite=false; 
    $email_exite=false; //verificar se o usuario existe 
    $sql= "select * from usuarios where usuario = '$usuarios'";

    if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id); 
        if(isset($dados_usuario['usuario'])){
            echo 'usuario ja exitente';
        } else {
            echo 'erro ao tentar localizar o usuario';
        }
```

Comment: Precisamos ver o código pra conseguir ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

Você esqueceu de fechar a chave do `if`:

```
<?php 
require_once('db.class.php'); 
$usuarios = $_POST['usuario']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$senha = md5($_POST['senha']); 
$objDB= new db(); 
$link= $objDB->conecta_mysql(); 

$usuario_exite=false; 
$email_exite=false; //verificar se o usuario existe 
$sql= "select * from usuarios where usuario = '$usuarios'"; 

if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) { 
  $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id); 
  if(isset($dados_usuario['usuario'])){ echo 'usuario ja exitente'; } 
  else { echo 'erro ao tentar localizar o usuario'; } 
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada!